# Is it possible to remove input type=file selections with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, forms

If you have an HTML form with an element like this:

```
<input type="file" name="file" multiple="multiple">
```

Then normally it would allow the user to select multiple files to upload, and they all get sent to the server with the same form field name "file".

I understand that due to security reasons, browsers won't let JavaScript just set any value for the selected files, and that's a good thing.

I just wonder though, once the user has selected the files, I would like to have multiple forms perform the uploads individually.  Is there a way to either:

- Clone the input item into each new form, and programatically remove
  file selections from each element?
- Transfer some of their selections
  to a separate input type=file element, or even a different form on
  the screen?

Comment: Perhaps this is a case for the [new Files API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)?

Comment: @Charles: It will be, when IE8 and 9 are dead. :-) http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, man, way to rain on my parade.  Coulda sworn it was in IE9 at least.

Comment: @Charles: :-) The good news there is most people who have/had IE9 are on the auto-upgrade path and have probably already been moved to IE10 or IE11. IE8 is the big pain, with being the max available for XP (and XP isn't dying any time soon). Doesn't mean you can't use the File API if the browser supports it and give IE8 users a poorer user experience. Still (far) too many IE8 users to just ignore them, though, sadly. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you clone an `input[type=file]` element, the clone's value is blank. You also cannot copy the value from one file input to another.

I've never tried to *move* a file input from one document to another after the file is selected. I'd like to think the browser would clear the selection when you did that, too, but it may not. *(Update: Of three browsers tested, all of them **retained** the value, to my surprise. See below.)*

Fundamentally, if you want to use separate forms to upload the files individually, you'll want the inputs in separate forms to begin with, *before* the user makes their selections. But apparently you may be able to move them, which would let you do what you want to do. I'd still probably start out with separate forms, to avoid having to move them.

---

Interestingly, Chrome, Firefox, and IE10 at least seem perfectly happy to *move* a file element with its selection intact, even to a different document: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/yosil/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/yosil/1/edit)

HTML:

```
<input id="theFile" type="file">
<br>Choose a file above, then either:
<br><input type="button" id="btnClone" value="Clone">
<input type="button" id="btnMove" value="Move to iframe">
<br>
<iframe id="theFrame" style="width: 99%"></iframe>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function() {
  gid("btnClone").onclick = function() {
    display("Here's the clone:");
    document.body.appendChild(gid("theFile").cloneNode(true));
  };
  gid("btnMove").onclick = function() {
    gid("theFrame").contentDocument.body.appendChild(gid("theFile"));
    display("File input moved to the iframe");
  };

  function gid(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
  }

  function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = String(msg);
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
})();
```

With the above, if I select something and click the *Move to iframe* button, the input is moved, apparently intact. (Cloning clears the value, as expected.)